# paste doesn't work on save file dialog name input

Tags: files, dialog, paste

I'm using ubuntu 22.04.3 and when I try to paste text in the save file dialog name input sometimes it doesn't work. I noticed it while using libre office, but it is set to use system dialogs, not its own. I have tried both using ctrl+v and right click and paste as I saw suggested in another post, but it had no effect. The copied text is stored on the clipboard, because I can still paste it normally on a text editor for example, but it just doesn't get pasted on the name input. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: "The save file dialog": of which program? All programs or only some? Add some indication to your question in what apps this happens - use "edit" to update your question. Do not use a comment: Information in comments may not be seen, and comments may disappear.